# Windows Phone 7 Settings

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've noticed that in the Phone 7 Beta emulator there is a settings application. It contains an "applications" panel. This seems to imply that we should be writing settings plugins so that settings for all apps are managed centrally, similarly to how the iPhone settings work.

Does anyone know how we write/register these plugins? Or if I'm on completely the wrong track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All settings and configuration for any application you create should be managed from within that application.
This is different from the iPhone where settings and configuration are considered separate and should be managed in separate places.
The Settings "application" on the device/emulator contains system settings and what it calls "application" settings.  What are termed applicatoin settings actually relate to hub settings (plus IE & Search).

From the [UI Design and Interaction Guide for Windows Phone 7 version 2.0](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713252) (page 66 - System and system application settings)

> "Application settings must be
>   implemented within the application
>   itself."

Comment: Is there no way to share application settings? Let's assume I am using a Webservice that requires login and some preferences. I really need to configure it in all my applications again?

Comment: @rudelm there is no way to share settings between apps. You must add the functionality for each app

Comment: thank you for the assurance. I hope there will be some day a place in WP7 to aggregate all application settings from one developers apps and/or services. It would make initial app setup easier and comfortable while on the other hand misuse may occur through shared access.

Comment: You can share settings. The sharing scope "is determined by the full path of the application .xap file". See the 'Remarks' section on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(VS.95).aspx

Comment: @Schneider settings can be shared across Silverlight apps running in the same domain. On the phone apps are not in a domain and can't share settings. Phone app settings are only at the application level and are stored in a file saved in isolated storage that are sandboxed and not available to other applications.

Comment: I stand corrected. MSDN is not very clear about SL vs Phone, I keep falling into trap of thinking SL = Phone

Answer (score 1):

MSDN: [How to: Create a Settings Page for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Edit:I just tried the SettingsSample and that doesn't appear in the OS settings page but I think that is the [plan in the final SDK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/e47edfb4-feba-421e-a0d4-6fedb1337b48) this functionality should be available.

Comment: The post you reference is out of date. From the designg guidelines: "Developers do not have access to place application settings within the System and System Application Settings and must implement application settings pages within the application itself."

Comment: I stand corrected, the MSDN link may still have some use. I'll upvote your answer. I had seen a few previews that had pointed out that feature, perhaps it will return.