# WP7 application settings page in the OS's application settings?

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings

I saw that Internet Explorer's settings are available both from the application and the OS's settings (actually, the application points to the settings page in the OS). Is there any way to manually or (preferably) programmatically add my application's settings page there?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706063/windows-phone-7-settings

Comment: Thanks. The answer is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't implemented in the current release of the tools.

Settings are via app's own pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not available in the SDK for the current release.  Hopefully they support it down the line, but you need to write your own settings page right now and have it navigable to from within your app.