# Having an entry in Settings >> Applications in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706063/windows-phone-7-settings)

In wp7, there's a Settings app. One of the pivot items is "applications". Is it possible for third party developers to have entries there? Or is that just for first party apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706063/windows-phone-7-settings), application settings must be implemented within the application itself